# PHPMAILER not sending select input

Tags: php, angularjs, phpmailer

Hi my question is about the following i'm using the `select` tag in my form, but the value does not get passed on to the email that gets send out.

I've created an app using PHPMAILER and have added the `select` tag with options included. whenever I hit send I get the following error:

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"contact-form.php","data":"inputPrice=1%20%2F%202%20hour%20%3D%2020%2C-&inputGuests=1&inputDate=Mon%20Feb%2003%201992%2010%3A10%3A00%20GMT%2B0100%20(Central%20European%20Standard%20Time)&inputMessage=Mon%20Feb%2003%201992%2010%3A10%3A00%20GMT%2B0100%20(Central%20European%20Standard%20Time)&inputName=Salman%20Mohamed&inputEmail=salmannova%40gmail.com&inputNumber=620438661","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"abort"}
```

The email does get send with all the value's added except the value from the `select` tag. In the error you can read that the value does get passed on, but for some reason doesn't get passed onto the email.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

**Select module**

```
  <select ng-model="formData.inputPrice" type="number" class="form-control inputForm fa fa-input" id="inputPrice" name="inputPrice" placeholder="How many scooters?" required>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Prices</option>
    <option value="1 / 2 hour = 20,-">1 / 2 hour = 20,-</option>
    <option value="1 day = 30,-">1 day = 30,-</option>
    <option value="2 days = 55,-">2 days = 55,</option>
    <option value="3+ dagen = +20,-">3+ dagen = +20</option>
  </select>
```

**mail.html**

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">

            </div>
            <div ng-controller="ContactController" class="panel-body">
                <form ng-submit="submit(contactform)" name="contactform" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                  <div class="steps stepOneWhite" id="stepOne">

                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputPrice.$invalid && submitted }">
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                          <select ng-model="formData.inputPrice" type="number" class="form-control inputForm fa fa-input" id="inputPrice" name="inputPrice" placeholder="How many scooters?" required>
                            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Prices</option>
                            <option value="1 / 2 hour = 20,-">1 / 2 hour = 20,-</option>
                            <option value="1 day = 30,-">1 day = 30,-</option>
                            <option value="2 days = 55,-">2 days = 55,</option>
                            <option value="3+ dagen = +20,-">3+ dagen = +20</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputGuests.$invalid && submitted }">
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input ng-model="formData.inputGuests" type="number" class="form-control inputForm fa fa-input" id="inputGuests" name="inputGuests" placeholder="How many scooters?" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h2>Pick up</h2>
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputDate.$invalid && submitted }">
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input ng-model="formData.inputDate" type="datetime-local" class="form-control inputForm fa fa-input" id="inputDate" name="inputDate" placeholder="Your Date" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h2>Return</h2>
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputMessage.$invalid && submitted }">
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input ng-model="formData.inputMessage" type="datetime-local" class="form-control inputForm fa fa-input" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="&#xf075" required></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="steps stepTwoWhite" id="stepTwo">
                      <h2>Your Information</h2>

                      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputName.$invalid && submitted }">
                          <div class="col-lg-10">
                              <input ng-model="formData.inputName" type="text" class="form-control  inputForm fa fa-input" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="&#xf007" required>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputEmail.$invalid && submitted }">
                          <div class="col-lg-10">
                              <input ng-model="formData.inputEmail" type="email" class="form-control inputForm fa fa-input" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="&#xf0e0" required>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputNumber.$invalid && submitted }">
                          <div class="col-lg-10">
                              <input ng-model="formData.inputNumber" type="number" class="form-control inputForm fa fa-input" id="inputNumber" name="inputNumber" placeholder="&#xf095" required>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block submitInputWhite" id="submitInput" ng-disabled="submitButtonDisabled">
                                Send Message
                            </button>
                            <span id="rentButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block rentButtonWhite" onclick="rentNowWhite()">Rent!</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <p ng-class="result" style="padding: 15px; margin: 0;">{{ resultMessage }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**contact-form.php**

```
   <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['inputName']) && isset($_POST['inputEmail']) && isset($_POST['inputNumber']) && isset($_POST['inputGuests']) && isset($_POST['inputDate'])  && isset($_POST['inputMessage']) && isset($_POST['inputPrice'])) {

    //check if any of the inputs are empty
    if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || empty($_POST['inputNumber']) || empty($_POST['inputGuests']) || empty($_POST['inputDate']) || empty($_POST['inputMessage']) || empty($_POST['inputPrice']) ) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    //create an instance of PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From = $_POST['inputEmail'];
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['inputName'];
    $mail->AddAddress('salman-1992@hotmail.com'); //recipient 
    $mail->Subject = "Nieuwe reservering is binnengekomen";
    $mail->Body = "Nieuwe reservering:". "\r\n\r\nNaam: " . $_POST['inputName'] . "\r\n\r\nTelefoonnummer: " . $_POST['inputNumber'] ."\r\n\r\nAantal Gasten: " . $_POST['inputGuests'] ."\r\n\r\nDatum: " . $_POST['inputDate'] . $_POST['inputMessage'] . $_POST['inputPrice']);

    if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
        $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
    }

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thanks! We have received your message.');
    echo json_encode($data);

} else {

    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = 'hidden'
    $scope.resultMessage;
    $scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
    $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
    $scope.submit = function(contactform) {
        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
        if (contactform.$valid) {
            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'contact-form.php',
                data    : $.param($scope.formData),  //param method from jQuery
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            }).success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result='bg-success';
                } else {
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result='bg-danger';
                }
            });
        } else {
            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
            $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed :( Please fill out all the fields.';
            $scope.result='bg-danger';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks like a Javascript problem, not PHP?

Comment: how come? Do I need to inject the select ?

Comment: The simple fact that you’re returning JSON suggests you’re not submitting from a regular form post. That error looks like it was generated client-side, not from PHP, so I think your issue occurs before it reaches PHP, so has nothing to do with your script.

Comment: But isn't it strange that all the other inputs do reach the script?

Comment: We can't tell because you've not included your JS. I'd recommend `var_dump($_POST)` in your script to see what you're receiving, and test your PHP separately from your JS.

Comment: added the script. I'm using AngularJS and posting directly to the php using the `action="` doesn't work. I'll try to add `var_dump($_POST)` to see what happens

Comment: The var_dump *will* break your JS, but that's why I said to test it separately from your JS. You could also set a breakpoint in your JS so you can inspect what it's submitting before it does so. That `$.param($scope.formData)` is evidently returning `null` looks very suspicious to me.

Comment: also very odd. I found out after changing one of the previous inputs to the select and it works, but prices doesn't get send. It's really wierd